# Can I activate Wake-On-LAN outside my local network?

Tags: networking, lan, wake-on-lan

I'd like to have some way to send the packet to my computer, say from another network. Is that possible? What would be the best way to do that, if possible? Like, can I just open port 9 and have the settings correct?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your router you may be able to send a packet to the router and port forward UDP port 9 on the broadcast address of your internal network (often x.x.x.255, where x.x.x are the first 3 octets of your local IP address).

Comment: So I just tested this a minute ago with the iOS App I have, I set the MAC address as the same, but I changed the internal IP of the computer to my external IP. I also forwarded the port 9 to the target computer, and it worked fine. EDIT: So I can just enable UDP? I had it set to TCP and UDP,  would it make a difference if I changed it?

Comment: @Pocketkid2, while this does work on some routers, it is ***highly dangerous*** to allow anybody on the public Internet to send broadcasts on your local network. Better would be to have a WoL server on your network, either a stand-alone server, or one built into your router.

Comment: What is a WoL server? Is there no way to make it more secure with my current setup? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Pocketkid2, it is software which runs on a PC, server, or some routers. You can send it unicast packets to tell it to WoL a particular IP address. Allowing anyone to send broadcasts on your network is tantamount to turning off your firewall since each and every device on a LAN must stop and read broadcasts, and you would have no control over the content of the broadcasts being delivered on your network.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I open port 9, then the WoL packet comes in as a broadcast, and everyone sees it even if its not for them? But doesn't my router forward the packet to my IP that I set?

Comment: @Pocketkid2, by definition, broadcasts are addressed to every device on a LAN, and all device _must_ stop and process a broadcast. Forwarding as davidgo described is forwarded to the broadcast address (everyone), not just a single device. I could then send bad stuff (not just WoL) to port 9 on your router and pwn all your LAN devices, or, more simply, perform a DoS attack by overloading your LAN devices with broadcasts.

Comment: @RonMaupin (sorry we disagree so much !). I agree that running a WoL server is a god idea, but dont think a broadcast limited to UDP port 9 is that dangerous - if a service is not listening on that port, it won't have any affect -   Its not so arbitrary it can proble/exploit other services.  There is very limited potential for a DoS attack but a home LAN is typically small, and the chances of getting it working with a broadcast are, much higher then having a WoL router in a home-network router.  I've been unable to find any compromises based on WOL from a WAN port - can you point me to any ?

Comment: There are some home routers and/or home router software (e.g. DD-WRT) which implement WoL in a more secure fashion. There are also secure, inexpensive, easy solutions for a WoL server in a home network (e.g. http://www.jeremyblum.com/2013/07/14/rpi-wol-server/).

Comment: My only concern is that there is a very real problem with complete ignorance of security in the world of home networking, and this is borne out but the prevalence of botnets, or simply look at all the questions on Super User by people infected with one thing or another. The bad guys know what the residential ISP subnets are, and I can get dozens of break-in attempts within five minutes of turning on a device to a new residential ISP address; these are obviously automated attacks. I know someone serving time in Federal Prison due to a pwned network.

Comment: @RonMaupin at the risk of getting off topic, Save for WIFI compromises most are not the result of the network, rather the result of users doing stupid things on their computer or having inadequate antivirus/antimalware.  I fear that giving people security advice without being able to point out or quantifying the specific risks leads to a culture of fear and not embracing technology appropriately.